# Why is Ajax/Flask returning value undefined?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to build a very simple website using flask + html + other python scripts + JQuery. So far the html + JQuery part of it is working but whenever I try to return the value from my python script it returns undefined and I'm not sure why.

html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
    $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/task/",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            data: { echoValue: $('input[name="echoText"]').val() },
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data.value)
            $('#echoResult').text(data.value);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });     
  });
});
</script>
<strong>Enter a value:</strong>
<input type='text' size='10' id='echoText' name='echoText'>
<button type='button' id='submitBtn' name='submitBtn'>Submit via AJAX</button><br /><br   />
<strong></strong>
</br>

{% endblock %}
```

flask:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, Response
import re
from MyFunction import *
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'F34TF$($e34D';

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/task/")   
def some_function():
    testdata = {"value": request.args.get('echoValue')}
    return Response(test(testdata['value']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

python script:

```
def test(value):
    return value
```

Comment: Have you set the global `$SCRIPT_ROOT`? `$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};`? From here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/#where-is-my-site

Answer (score 0):

I changed your function slightly, remove `$` sign from beginning of your variable and also `.data` from the returned value. To set input value I used `val()` method. Moreover you don't need `SCRIPT_ROOT` at all:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
    $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/task/",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            data: { echoValue: $('input[name="echoText"]').val() },
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
            $('#echoResult').val(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });     
  });
});
</script>
```